# How to make the Django template include work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have three pages main,one and two. i requirement is when i visit the page main i need to see the page one and two.

HTML:

**`main.html`**

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load my_tag %}

{% block title %}
  <title>Main TAB</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
  <div>
    {% include ‘test/one/’ %}
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    {{name}}
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/testquery.js"%}">
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**`one.html`**

```
<div class="container">
  {{ name }}
</div>
```

**`two.html`**

```
<div class="container">
  {{ name }}
</div>
```

**`view.py`**

```
def main_page(request):
    try:
        main_data = {'name':"main"}
        return render(request, 'task/main.html', {'name': main_data})

    except Exception as e:
        raise

def one_page(request):
    try:
        main_data = "one"
        return render(request, 'task/one.html', {'name': main_data})

    except Exception as e:
        raise

def two_page(request):
    try:
        main_data = "Two"
        return render(request, 'task/two.html', {'name': main_data})

    except Exception as e:
        raise
```

**`url.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', taskpage,name="task_master"),
    path('Task/<int:taskid>', show_task,name='show_task'),
    path('Task/<int:taskid>/update', 
        updatetaskpage,name='updatetask_page'),
    path('Test/Main/', main_page,name='main'),
    path('Test/one/', one_page,name='one'),
    path('Test/two/', two_page,name='two'),
]
```

I am getting the following error :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /taskmaster/Test/Main/
Could not parse the remainder: '‘test/one.html’' from '‘test/one.html’'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/taskmaster/Test/Main/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '‘test/one.html’' from '‘test/one.html’'
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 668
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\i326707\\PycharmProjects\\opsboard',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\i326707\\PycharmProjects\\opsboard\\commonpage',
 'C:\\Users\\i326707\\PycharmProjects\\opsboard\\taskmaster']
Server time:    Sat, 23 Dec 2017 08:10:28 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have curly quotes in your include tag, which aren't valid. Replace them with straight single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951170/400691) correctly points out that you are using curly quotes. This should be fixed.

There is another issue -- you're incorrectly passing a URL to `include`. Instead, should be passing the filepath to the template that you're including (relative to the `templates` directory). ie:

```
{% include 'task/one.html' %}
```

See the [docs for the `include` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include).